# How to prove that $x^{\frac{1}{\log_a(x)}}$ is a constant?

Tags: logarithms, solution-verification

Are the following lines a valid proof that $x^{\frac{1}{\log_a(x)}}$ is a constant?

$$K = x^{\frac{1}{\log_a(x)}}$$
$$\log_a(K) = \frac{\log_a(x)}{\log_a(x)} = 1, \text{ for } x \notin \{0, 1\}$$
$$K = a$$

If not, how does one prove this?

Comment: Looks good to me... Equivalently, $x = a^{\log_a x}$, by definition.

Comment: With, as you suggest, reasonable values of $x$ and $a$ for things to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using change of base formula (i.e. $\log_p(q)=\frac{\log q}{\log p}$), we can show that $\frac{1}{\log_p (q)}=\log_q (p)$.

This means $K=x^{\log_x (a)}=a$

Answer (score 3):

The proof looks valid to me. I used natural logarithms instead of logarithms with base $a$, which makes the proof slightly longer:

$$ K=x^{\frac{1}{\log_ax}} \\ \\
\begin{align}
\ln K &=\ln\left(x^{\frac{1}{\log_ax}}\right) \\ 
&=\frac{1}{\log_ax}\ln x \\ \\
&=\frac{1}{\frac{\ln x}{\ln a}}\ln x \\ \\
&=\frac{\ln a}{\ln x}\ln x \\ \\
&= \ln a
\end{align} $$

and, as such, $K=a$. Your proof is much better, though!

Answer (score 3):

Using that $(a^s)^t = a^{st}$ we get $\color{red}{x}^{\tfrac{1}{\log_a x}} = \color{red}{(a^{\log_a x})}^{\tfrac{1}{\log_a x}} = a^{1}$.